# Flask 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: reactjs, cors, flask-restful, react-fullstack

I am trying to configure the flask backend to react front end. Both of these are running in different ports so I am importing CORS to allow config the backend to work with an application that's located on a different port (backend is running on 5000 frontend is running on 3000).

Here's my setup that works:

main.py

```
app=Flask(__name__)
...
CORS(app)
```

App.js

```
  useEffect(
    ()=>{
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/recipe/hello')
      .then((response=>{console.log(response); return response.json()}))
      .then(data=>console.log(data))
      .catch(err=>console.log(err))
    },[]
  )
```

Package.json

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

It's weird how the front end has to have `proxy` set in package.json and then the fetch command has to have the full proxy path with `http://127.0.0.1:5000` (it doesn't work with `http://localhost:5000`)

Can someone please explain me what's going on here? Why does it have to be configured in this weird way to work and how I can fix it?

For more context: I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zr5jtRhUVJA.

Comment: https://medium.com/@dmadan86/run-chrome-browser-without-cors-by-disabling-web-security-d124ad4dd2cf

Comment: Does it work if you keep only '/recipe/hello' as the URL in your fetch, and keep the proxy setting as it is now?

Comment: @jolammi no it doesn't. That's why i'm confused.

Comment: Could you push your work into a gist or a public repo so that we could take a look into it?

Comment: https://github.com/Rupakshi1999/charity-tracker this is the repo but i have made other commits after that change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because mac had port 5000 reserved so localhost:5000 access is blocked. Fix is to specify another port to run the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Create React App in your project, you use a [proxy setting](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) to avoid Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issues during development.

This proxy forwards API requests made by your React app to another server, typically running on a different port or domain. This helps bypass the browser's Same-Origin Policy, ensuring your app can fetch data from external sources without problems during development. This setting is only for development and not used in production.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear in my post. I already have proxy setting set in package.json. But it still doesn't work so I am needing to also specify the full path of the running server with the ip to the front end.